Getting different accuracy in TensorFlow when training on batches vs whole dataset
I am messing around with an multi-class image classifier in TensorFlow using a 2d CNN. If I try to evaluate the test data in batches or as whole set I get very different accuracy values. I even tried doing the evaluation of the training set (batches vs whole set) and got an even larger difference. Am I doing or interpreting something wrong?
Also the data was imported using tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(dir)
from tf.keras.metrics import Accuracy
acc=Accuracy()
#code for evaluating in batches
acc.reset_state()
re.reset_state()
pre.reset_state()
for batch in test_set.as_numpy_iterator():
    X,y=batch
    y_pred=model.predict(X)
    y_labels=y_pred.argmax(axis=1)
    acc.update_state(y,y_labels)
acc.result()

#code for whole dataset evaluation
test_probs=model.predict(test_data)
test_pred_labels=test_probs.argmax(axis=1)
acc.update_state(test_pred_labels,test_labels)
acc.result()


First, it is unclear what your "acc" is. It might be a buggy implementation. Apart from it:

Depending how acc is implemented you might get wrong results if total dataset size is not divisible by batch_size (since average of averages is not the same as the average of the whole thing, unless each average of the same size)
acc.update_state(y,y_labels) puts real labels as first argument but acc.update_state(test_pred_labels,test_labels) puts them as a second one. It shouldn't matter for accuracy but it all depends on how things are implemented
If the  model uses batch normalization it will behave differently in batch mode vs over entire dataset


Sorry about the lack of clarity. acc is an instance of tensorflow's accuracy class.
